# How to deploy spring boot framework in tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have an application that dynamically generates several web application (war files) with the same dependencies (spring boot, kafka, etc.) .my question is how I can put all these dependencies in Tomcat  to reduce the size of the war files and after in my pom.xml I write for example.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you give more details on why you want multiple wars, Spring boot has embedded tomcat any reasons why you are not using it? my guess is you have multiple applications and you are trying to put them in a single tomcat instance. You can think more on better strategy to deploy your application(s)

Comment: yes, the wars files are generating from a DSL and I want to put them in the same tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I can think of is to add the common jars to Tomcat/lib/SharedFolder and include that under shared.loader in catalina.properties and then Add the jars as `provided` dependencies. I can see you have already added the `provided` tag.

I think that will work. I haven't tried it in a sample application but I remember helping my friend do something similar to what I described above.

Hope it helps